# How to run the same block of code - Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d and have 2 AI sprites called TheEvilOne and TheEvilTwo. These 2 sprites call the same bloc of code from the same class sending the sprite as a parameter. However the game gets buggy as I run this code as only one of the sprites preforms the actions and my code stops working. My question is is it possible to call the same bloc of code for multiple sprites simultaneously or is there something wrong with my code. Below is an example of what I am running on my program.

```
-(void)LoadingEvilActions:(id)sender {    //This is Getting Constantly Called
    if(loaded == NO) {
    theEvilOne = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Evil_Alt_Idle_00.png"]; //These sprites have been declared in my .h file
    [self addChild:theEvilOne z:200];
    theEvilTwo = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Evil_Alt_Idle_00.png"];
    [self addChild:theEvilTwo z:200];
     loaded = YES;
 }
    [self CheckCollision:theEvilOne];
    [self setCenterofScreen:theEvilOne];
    [self StayonScreen:theEvilOne];
    [self AiCharacter:theEvilOne];

    [self CheckCollision:theEvilTwo];
    [self setCenterofScreen:theEvilTwo];
    [self StayonScreen:theEvilTwo];
    [self AiCharacter:theEvilTwo];
}


-(void)AiCharacter:(id)sender {
    CCSprite *EvilCharacter = (CCSprite *)sender;
    if (aiactionrunning == NO){
    .... Do More Stuff // For E.G.
    id jump_Up = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:0.6f position:ccp(randomjump, EvilCharacter.contentSize.height)
                                                       height:25 jumps:1];
    id jump_Down = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:0.42f position:ccp(randomjump,-EvilCharacter.contentSize.height)
                                                         height:25 jumps:1];
    id seq = [CCSequence actions:jump_Up,jump_Down, [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stopAiAction:)], nil];
    [EvilCharacter stopAllActions];
    [EvilCharacter runAction:seq];
    aiactionrunning = YES;
    }
}
-(void)stopAiAction:(id)sender {
    aiactionrunning = NO;
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm running random number generators within my AI Character method and many actions.
The Game already works with just 1 enemy sprite and I decided to try and implement a way to create many.

**EDIT 2**

I just added the part of the method that stops the sprites being constantly, I was trying to simplify all the code that was irrelevant to my question and forgot to add that part.
I changed the way I am calling my methods like suggested by LearnCocos2d not solving my problem but making it much simpler. I am also not using ARC

One of my sprites is the only one preforming the majority of actions however in some instances the other sprite may preform an actions aswell, but is mainly preformed one sprite. I think my main question is can I call the same method using different sprites passing the sprite as a parameter.

**EDIT 3**

I have figured out that my problem is there is a Boolean value flag that is enclosing my AiCharacter method, where when one sprite runs through the method it stops the other sprite running the method. Is there some way I can implement an array of records or such so each sprite have their own Boolean flags.

With making this 'array' is it possible to change the Boolean for TheEvilOne and TheEvilTwo using the temp sprite EvilCharacter without doing both separately.

Comment: well the use of callfunc actions here is pointless, they are equivalent of sending the message directly as in [self CheckCollision:theEvilOne]; Perhaps you should check whether the two evil references actually point to two differrnt sprites, sounds like they are both the same. Ie post the code where you assign them

Comment: I wrote a basic how i initialized the sprites at the start of my loading evil actions function, not sure if that's what you asked for, thanks for the response

Comment: you are overwriting the pointers to the sprites every time you call that first function. move your `spriteWithFile` and `addChild` statements somewhere else that only gets called once, like `init` or `onEnter` or such. That should fix part of your issue.

Comment: Yeah in my code I already coded a solution to that but forgot to mention it when I simplified my code above. Thanks for reminding me to add it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you are trying to take one action and run it on more than one character at a time, like:

```
id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(0,0)];
[theEvilOne runAction:move];
[theEvilTwo runAction:move];
```

That wouldn't work because Evil 1 will not have anything performed on it since it was moved to running on Evil 2. When an action is running it is running on one target. Instead you would:

```
id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:ccp(0,0)];
[theEvilOne runAction:move];
[theEvilTwo runAction:[move copy]];
```

Assuming you are using arc. If not then you'd want to release the copy of course. When it comes to your particular example, why are you trying actions to call methods. Why not just call the method? It seems pointless as LearnCocos2D has pointed out.

Another potential problem you have is that you are constantly creating more and more sprites each time the method is called. Is that on purpose or are there only suppose to be one Evil 1 and one Evil 2? If so then you shouldn't be constantly creating more sprites.

**Edit:**

Remove your bool. Do something like this instead:

```
CCSprite *EvilCharacter = (CCSprite *)sender;

if ([EvilCharacter numberOfRunningActions] == 0){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the part that stops the loading of the sprite from occurring more than once, sorry about that. I am not using ARC within my code. The reason I have actions for calling methods is because I am inexperienced in programming as this is my first project which is for a school major and found this method on a site online, I have already changed it within my code and is still working as before. The way I am calling actions is written above using a temp sprite _EvilCharacter_ which I assume is a problem. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: In your edited code, what is stopAIAction and what does it look like? You don't need to stop actions that don't repeat. After the second jump the sequence would be over and the sequence action would be complete.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question above and added edit 3. Thanks for helping me out, the stopAiAction is just to stop some animations and remove sprites made by the method such as the AI Character shooting fireballs, and playing an idle animation once moves have been completed. It then calls the Boolean off and allows for the method to restart. Where i have written aiactionrunning = yes, is it possible to make the Boolean specific to the sprite that has been passed in as a paremeter. Maybe placing all my booleans in an array of records and doing something along those lines. Thanks for your time

Comment: I made an edit to my post. Remove your Boolean variable. Instead use the numberOfRunningActions method to see if the sprite has any actions running on it. See above.